# Please help me to understand this circuit (DC-DC HV generation 5 kV)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

Recently I had to improve very old style circuit, but could not understand its design fully. The attached schematic is the one I redrew from the original schematic (to simplify and clean.)

Basically this circuit works as a HV generator (24 VDC to 5 kVDC) - it is a DC-DC up-converter. The part I can't understand is the opamp (AD822) and buffer (BUF634) part.

Can anyone give me an idea (even a simple concept.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably ripple cancellation.

Consider the usual (series) voltage regulator circuit, embodied by LM317 and etc.: extra voltage (plus undesired ripple/noise) is applied to a pass device; the noise is subtracted out (plus some margin to account for tolerances), giving a stable output of the desired voltage.

Voltage can also be controlled by shunting the output, in which case a current-limited supply (or series resistor) is needed, and shunt current is varied to maintain output voltage as desired.  (See "zener regulator", TL431, etc.)

Neither of these make any statement about frequency range: indeed, the series regulator can be used at AC, as for example the "capacitor multiplier" (using a BJT emitter follower to effect filtering with much less capacitance than would be needed to brute-force filter the raw supply).  The only necessary cost is some drop in DC voltage, to power the active circuitry -- and even then, that doesn't necessarily have to come from the initial supply itself, it could be supplied from elsewhere!

In general, we could take a general-purpose amplifier, powered from its own independent supply, and wire it in series with another supply, then wire its inputs such that it produces an equal and opposite ripple voltage -- but only the AC component, with the DC decoupled or subtracted out.

A series connection doesn't care about the order of elements, so we could connect the amplifier at the + or - of the primary supply.

This is what has been done here: AD822 + BUF634 is an amplifier, running from an independent ±15V supply.  RV1 connects the output to the ground-return side of the high voltage supply.  (The true ground return, then, is the ±15V supply's ground return, not shown here.)  The input is configured so that any change in output voltage, with respect to ground (`0`), as determined by the differentiator C66 into U10A (note that R103 is superfluous; it's feeding a virtual ground node so there is already a bias path), is corrected by negative feedback.

Note that, if you completely remove the left half of the circuit -- short out the HV supply section -- you're left with a simple voltage follower circuit, albeit a somewhat odd one that's closing its own loop through a series capacitor (C66).  The effect is to reduce the AC impedance (and thus increase the immunity to noise) at the HV_OUT node (well, the other side of RV2 more specifically), while being able to add arbitrary DC to it.

This approach depends on the compliance range of the amplifier: it can only correct as much noise as falls within its voltage and current range.  If the load were stronger (a few too many mA, say?) (or C89 were too small, or the input frequency too low), the output ripple might grow too large, and the amplifier would go into clipping.  It would still be able to reduce ripple in that case, but only by 15V -- say, bringing 20V peak down to 5.

Another downside of this approach is poor high-frequency performance, as it depends on a control loop: the output impedance goes inductive at high frequencies where U10A's loop gain is rolling off (because it behaves as an integrator at high frequencies -- partly by design (dominant pole compensated), partly by additional effect of C68).  AD822 isn't a very fast amp itself, either (1.2MHz), so it seems a bit odd of a choice here, considering the input ripple is 93kHz and harmonics (note the PP drive and FWB rectifier effect a frequency doubling).  So it can only contribute about 20dB of attenuation (because it has a gain of ≤ 10 at these frequencies).

Less related to the control aspect, D55 is a nice touch: any transients at the output, especially large ones like a short circuit, will ram an enormous [displacement] current through C89.  Unfortunately this has not been repeated for C66's displacement current; R103 could be replaced with a TVS to afford this safety.  (Perhaps it's already there, and was just missed while tracing the circuit? Tracing is tricky work; it happens!)

Comment: Reallly appreciate clear answer "ripple cancellation" then following great exaplanation. (I made really nice choice to join this community and put this question here)